# CSS Float issue with IFrames

Tags: css, html, iframe, css-float

I added an Iframe to a page and it pushed my sidebar down.  I tried different ways to float it, but I'm still stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here's the HTML and CSS for the page:

http://lkwalker.com/writing.html

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>LK Walker</title>
  <meta name="description" content="website description" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <!-- modernizr enables HTML5 elements and feature detects -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <header>
      <div id="logo">
        <div id="logo_text">
          <!-- class="logo_colour", allows you to change the colour of the text -->
          <h1><a href="index.html">Lauren K. Walker
      <p><span class="logo_colour"> | Teacher | </span> <span class="logo_colour">Writer | </span></span> <span class="logo_colour">Yogi | </span></a></h1></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="retreats.html">Retreats</a></li>
          <li><a href="privates.html">Privates</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li><a href="EMyoga.html">Energy Medicine Yoga</a></li>
      <li><a href="military.html">Military</a></li>
      <li><a href="writing.html">Writing</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="social.html">Social Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="theater.html">Theatre</a></li>
          </ul>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      </nav>      
    </header>
    <div id="site_content">
      <div id="top_border"></div>   
      <ul id="images">
    <li><img src="images/lkwalker.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="LK Walker" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/navasana.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="Navasana" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/donna.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="Donna Eden" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/tree.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="Tree" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/raven.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="Birding" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/yogacow.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="Cow Pose" /></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Articles</h1>
    <iframe width="500" height="400" align="left" src ="http://lkwalkerwriting.blogspot.com/" width="500" height="500">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe><br />
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/15/education/edlife/upward-facing-soldier.html?smid=pl-share"> New York Times -
    Upward Facing Soldier </a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.mnn.com/health/fitness-well-being/stories/do-you-have-to-be-skinny-to-do-yoga">Mother Nature News -
    Do you need to be Skinny to do Yoga?</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.mnn.com/health/fitness-well-being/stories/what-is-energy-medicine-yoga"> Mother Nature News -
    What is Energy Medicine Yoga?</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="sidebar_container">
        <img class="paperclip" src="images/paperclip.png" alt="paperclip" />
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h4><p>Check out our newest clothing partner, <a href="http://www.mahadevidesign.com/">MahaDevi</a>, use code EMYoga to get a 15% discount.</p>
          <p><em>Like us on FaceBook - Follow us on Twitter</em><!-- START SOCIAL MEDIA WIDGET --><ul id="socialbar"><li id="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="htp://www.facebook.com/EnergyMedicineYoga"><IMG src="http://www.topproducerwebsite.com/images/site_defaults/generic/facebook.png"></a></li><li id="twitter"><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/energymedyoga"><IMG src="http://www.topproducerwebsite.com/images/site_defaults/generic/twitter.png"></a></li></ul><style>#socialbar img {border:0px;}#socialbar li img {width:48px; height:48px;}#socialbar li a:hover {position:relative;top:2px;}#socialbar{padding:0px;list-style: none outside none; margin:0px; position: static;}#socialbar li {display:inline;padding-right:2px;}#socialbar{width:180px;text-align:center;}</style><!-- END SOCIAL MEDIA WIDGET --></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <footer>
      <p>Copyright &copy; Energy Medicine Yoga| Whitefish, MT | <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a> |</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!-- javascript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing-sooper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sooperfish.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#images').kwicks({
        max : 600,
        spacing : 2
      });
      $('ul.sf-menu').sooperfish();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: Jacques Francois, times, serif; 
    src: url('../fonts/Jacques Francois.otf'); 
    src: local("Jacques Francois"), url('../fonts/Jacques Francois.otf'); 
} 

@font-face { 
  font-family: lilly, arial, sans-serif; 
    src: url('../fonts/lilly.ttf'); 
    src: local("lilly"), url('../fonts/lilly.ttf'); 
}

html { 
  height: 100%;
}

* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* tell the browser to render HTML 5 elements as block */
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { 
  display:block;
}

body { 
  font: normal .80em 'lilly', sans-serif;
  background: #cab0cb;
  color: #444;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
}

p { 
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

img { 
  border: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
  font-family: 'Jacques Francois', serif;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h2, h3 { 
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
}

h2 { 
  font-size: 160%;
  padding: 9px 0 5px 0;
  color: #04662e;
}

h3 { 
  font-size: 140%;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

h4, h6 { 
  color: #615044;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  font-family: normal 160% 'Jacques Francois', serif;
  font: bold 145% times, serif;
}

h5, h6 { 
  color: #615044;
  font: italic 95% times, serif;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
}

a, a:hover { 
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #B30303;
}

a:hover { 
  text-decoration: none;
}

blockquote { 
  margin: 20px 0; 
  padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #E5E5DB;
  background: #FFF;
}

ul { 
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
  clear: both;
}

ul li { 
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0; 
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

ol { 
  margin: 8px 0 22px 20px;
}

ol li { 
  margin: 0 0 11px 0;
}

.left { 
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right { 
  float: right; 
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.center { 
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

#main, nav, #container, #logo, #site_content, footer
  { 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
  }

#main {
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: 940px;
  background: transparent;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}


header { 
  background: transparent;
  height: 130px;
}

#logo { 
  width: 940px;
  height: 140px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #888;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AFABAB;}

#logo h1, #logo h2 { 
  font-family: normal 320% 'Jacques Francois', times, serif;
  border-bottom: 0;
  text-transform: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#logo_text h1, #logo_text h1 a, #logo_text h1 a:hover { 
  padding: 0;
  color: #331d59;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 48px;
}

#logo_text h1 a .logo_colour { 
  color: #2c89b3;
}

#logo_text a:hover .logo_colour { 
  color: #2c89b3;
}

#logo_text h2 { 
  font-size: 140%;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  color: #04662e;
}

nav { 
  height: 44px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:90%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #222;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  width: 100%;
}

iframe
  { 
  width: 60%;
  clear: both;

  }

#site_content { 
  width: 940px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AFABAB;   
} 

#top_border {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;   
  padding-top: 20px;} 

#sidebar_container { 
  float: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.sidebar { 
  float: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 0 17px 0;
  background: #EFF8FB;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  padding: 0 15px 5px 13px;
}

.sidebar h3, .content h1 { 
  padding: 0 15px 20px 0;
  font: 230% 'Days', arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: bold;
  text-shadow:  #FFF 1px 1px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  color: #444;
}

.sidebar h3 { 
  color: #444;
  font: 250% 'Lilly', arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 15px 5px 0;  
}

.sidebar ul { 
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
} 

.sidebar li a, .sidebar li a:hover { 
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
} 

.sidebar li a:hover { 
  text-decoration: underline;
} 

.sidebar_item, .content_item { 
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.paperclip { 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 0;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  margin: -15px 0 -60px -40px;
}

.content { 
  text-align: left;
  width: 670px;
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.content ul { 
  margin: 2px 0 22px 0px;
}

.content ul li, .sidebar ul li { 
  list-style-type: none;
  background: url(../images/bullet.png) no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 0 0; 
  padding: 0 0 4px 28px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

footer { 
  width: 940px;
  clear: both;
  font: 170% 'Lilly', arial, sans-serif;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 10px solid #eeeeee;
}

footer p { 
  line-height: 1.7em;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  color: #000;
}

footer a { 
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: 1px 1px #FFF;
}

footer a:hover { 
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.form_settings { 
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.form_settings p { 
  padding: 0 0 4px 0;
}

.form_settings span { 
  float: left; 
  width: 200px; 
  text-align: left;
}

.form_settings input, .form_settings textarea { 
  padding: 5px; 
  width: 299px; 
  font: 100% arial; 
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5; 
  background: #FFF; 
  color: #47433F;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;  
}

.form_settings .submit { 
  font: 140% 'Days', arial, sans-serif; 
  border: 0; 
  width: 99px; 
  margin: 0 0 0 212px; 
  height: 33px;
  padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
  cursor: pointer; 
  background: #ddd; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 2px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  color: #222;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #FFF;
}

.form_settings textarea, .form_settings select { 
  font: 100% arial; 
  width: 299px;
}

.form_settings select { 
  width: 310px;
}

.form_settings .checkbox { 
  margin: 4px 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  width: 14px;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
}

.separator { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #D9D5CF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

table { 
  margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
}

table tr th, table tr td { 
  background: #BBB;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 7px 4px;
  text-align: left;
}

table tr td { 
  background: #DDD;
  color: #444;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
}

/* Image Transitions */
ul#images {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul#images li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 155px;
  height: 300px;
}

/**
Stylesheet for SooperFish by www.SooperThemes.com
Author: Jurriaan Roelofs
**/

/* Configuration of menu width */
html body ul.sf-menu ul,html body ul.sf-menu ul li { 
  width: 200px;
}

html body ul.sf-menu ul ul { 
  margin: 0 0 0 200px;
}

/* Framework for proper showing/hiding/positioning */
ul.sf-menu,ul.sf-menu * { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.sf-menu { 
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

ul.sf-menu li { 
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

ul.sf-menu li:hover { 
  visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */ 
}

ul.sf-menu a { 
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

ul.sf-menu ul { 
  position: absolute;
  width:70%;
  top: auto;
}

ul.sf-menu ul a { 
  zoom: 1; /* IE6/7 fix */ 
}

ul.sf-menu ul li { 
  float: left; /* Must always be floated otherwise there will be a rogue 1px margin-bottom in IE6/7 */
  width: 150px;
}

ul.sf-menu ul ul { 
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 150px;
}

ul.sf-menu li:hover ul,ul.sf-menu li:focus ul,ul.sf-menu li.sf-hover ul, 
ul.sf-menu ul li:hover ul,ul.sf-menu ul li:focus ul,ul.sf-menu ul li.sf-hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:hover ul,ul.sf-menu ul ul li:focus ul,ul.sf-menu ul ul li.sf-hover ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:hover ul,ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:focus ul,ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li.sf-hover ul { 
  left: auto;
}

ul.sf-menu li:hover ul ul,ul.sf-menu li:focus ul ul,ul.sf-menu li.sf-hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul li:hover ul ul,ul.sf-menu ul li:focus ul ul,ul.sf-menu ul li.sf-hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul li:hover ul ul,ul.sf-menu ul ul li:focus ul ul,ul.sf-menu ul ul li.sf-hover ul ul,
ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:hover ul ul,ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li:focus ul ul,ul.sf-menu ul ul ul li.sf-hover ul ul { 
  left: -999999px;
}

/* autoArrows CSS */
span.sf-arrow { 
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: url(../images/arrows-black.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* making sure IE6 doesn't overflow and expand the box */
  font-size: 1px;
}

ul ul span.sf-arrow { 
  right: 5px;
  top: 20px;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}

/* Theming the menu */
ul#nav { 
  float: left;
}

ul#nav ul { 
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

ul#nav li a { 
  padding: 7px 18px 6px 18px;
  font: 150% 'Lilly', arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

ul#nav li a:hover, ul#nav li a:focus, ul#nav li.selected a, ul#nav li.selected a:hover, ul#nav li.selected a:focus { 
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
}

ul#nav ul li a { 
  color: #000;
}

ul#nav ul li a:hover { 
  color: #B30303;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

/* Image Transitions */
ul#images {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul#images li {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 155px;
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a www.jsfiddle.net demonstration or a screen shot of your error for more clear illustration.

Comment: The `img.paperclip` has a negative margin which can push the sidebar down. The width of the `<ul>` below the iframe isn't set. You should check the width of each element with Firebug or another debugging tool. You can also increase the page width.

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar_container {
     float: right;
     vertical-align: top;
     display: inline;
     width: 200px;
     margin: 0 0 0 0;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 536px;
     left: 269px;
}
```

Add these lines to your sidebar_container id and try!!

Also you had added an iframe and this `side_bar` class in a single main div, and haven't specified their positions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of `</div>` closing.

Cut and paste the entire sidebar container after closing of `</div>`

**Now**

```
<div id="content">

bla bla bla

<div id="sidebar-container">
   bla bla bla

</div> <!-- closing sidebar  -->
</div> <!-- closing content  -->
```

**Change it to**

```
<div id="content">
bla bla bla
</div> <!-- closing content  -->

<div id="sidebar-container">
   bla bla bla
</div> <!-- closing sidebar  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue not with iframe it is causing because of **UL**

Its taking its space you left content in div like

```
<div class="left_container">
<!-left content-->

    <iframe width="65%" height="400" align="left" src="http://lkwalkerwriting.blogspot.com/">
      &amp;amp;lt;p&amp;amp;gt;Your browser does not support iframes.&amp;amp;lt;/p&amp;amp;gt;
    </iframe><br>
    <ul style="
    /* width: 108px; */
    /* float: left; */
    clear: both;
">
    <li><a href="http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/15/education/edlife/upward-facing-soldier.html?smid=pl-share"> New York Times -
    Upward Facing Soldier </a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.mnn.com/health/fitness-well-being/stories/do-you-have-to-be-skinny-to-do-yoga">Mother Nature News -
    Do you need to be Skinny to do Yoga?</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.mnn.com/health/fitness-well-being/stories/what-is-energy-medicine-yoga"> Mother Nature News -
    What is Energy Medicine Yoga?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div class="sidebar_container">

  <!--sidebar content-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left_container
{
width: 69%;
float: left;
}
```

remain css is same as yours thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a messy fix but should resolve the issue for the moment. If you make these changes in your css it should all line up. I used Firebug on firefox to test it and it worked just fine.

```
.content {
    float: left;
    font-size: 120%;
    margin: 25px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 940px;
}

.content ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 0 22px;
}

sidebar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFF8FB;
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin: -450px 0 17px;
    padding: 0 15px 5px 13px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 180px;
}
```

I would not suggest this is a permanent solution but it should help in the meantime